# В чем отличие @yield от @show?

Tags: laravel

В чем отличие `@yield` от `@show` разве они не выполняют одно и то же действие?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Нет. У этих директив разное назначение.

`@show`, как и `@endsection`, используется для обозначения конца секции.

`@show` выводит содержимое секции на экран, сразу после объявления секции.
`@endsection` не делает ничего, кроме обозначения конца объявления секции.
`@show` и `@endsection` не могут существовать без предшествующей директивы `@section`.

`@yield` используется для вывода содержимого секции с определенным именем.
Эта директива вполне может существовать без предшествующей директивы `@section`, если та, например, была объявлена в одном из дочерних шаблонов.
Возможен вариант использования `@yield`, когда секция с указанным именем вообще не была объявлена, тогда надо передать в нее второй параметр, который будет служить значением по умолчанию.

---

Пример шаблона:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Мое приложение @yield('non-existent-section', 'работает')</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @section('displayed-content')
            Это содержимое секции, которое будет сразу выведено на экран.
        @show

        @section('declared-content')
            Это содержимое секции, для вывода которого надо использовать @yield
        @endsection

        <div class="content">
            <!-- выводим содержимое секции declared-content на экран -->
            @yield('declared-content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Пример итогового файла:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Мое приложение работает</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Это содержимое секции, которое будет сразу выведено на экран.
        <div class="content">
            <!-- выводим содержимое секции declared-content на экран -->
            Это содержимое секции, для вывода которого надо использовать @yield
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

[Подробнее в документации](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/templates)

---

### В чем отличие `@endsection` от `@stop`

Как говорится в этом [сообщении](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33321717/2486051) на SO:

**Существует авторитетный ответ от Taylor Otwell**

> Директива `@endsection` стала `@stop` в L4, а `@yieldSection` стала `@show`.

[Оригинальная цитата Taylor Otwell на github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/978#issuecomment-16510172).

В Laravel 5 можно использовать любой из вариантов: `@endsection` или `@stop`.
Отличий в функционале нет, это одно и то же.

Comment: Разве вместо endsection не используется stop?

Comment: @quaresma89, я дополнил ответ